# Help with black parts on render

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view

I am trying to render this and when i do so, these black parts appear.
Can anyone help, how to get rid of them and why does this happen?[image]

Comment: Maybe it happens because you have overlapping faces, try to select all and merge by distance in Edit mode

Comment: Thank you very much moonboots, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping faces, it creates bad artefacts (it's called Z fighting), select all and merge by distance in *Edit* mode (<kbd>M</kbd>)

Comment: Thank you, it worked!